Symfony FileUploader Dependency Injection Arguments
I'm following this example given in the official Symfony documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html
It moves the uploader logic into a service and then reduces the code of the controller to this:
public function new(Request $request, FileUploader $fileUploader): Response
{
    // ...

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        /** @var UploadedFile $brochureFile */
        $brochureFile = $form->get('brochure')->getData();
        if ($brochureFile) {
            $brochureFileName = $fileUploader->upload($brochureFile);
            $product->setBrochureFilename($brochureFileName);
        }

        // ...
      }

   // ...
   }

So my question is: how will the service get the value of the $targetDirectory argument?
I know it's configured in the services config file, but this is the config in that tutorial:
services:
    # ...

    App\Service\FileUploader:
        arguments:
           $targetDirectory: '%brochures_directory%'

Where is that brochures_directory? Where is it coming from? The controller after the update doesn't have a declaration or annotation of any brochures_directory or brochuresDirectory.
What if I want to use that service with a different directory? Now it seems to be restricted only to brochures.

Hi, this is a parameter that you hace to define on services.yml, see https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-parameters

Thanks, that seems to be working. Isn't there a way to have it more flexible and generic? Now that parameter's value is set to the profile image directory, because that's what I'm going to upload. But what if in the future I want to upload files in a different target directory, like brochures for example. I think there was an annotation to initialize the value of that parameter in the controller (or wherever the service is being injected), but I cannot find it. That documentation page should be more specific about this, what's the point to create a service class, if its use is so restricted.

You can add getter and setter for $targetDirectory to that service, and set it from controller

I thought about that, just tried to keep things more Symfony-ish . But cannot find any other way in the documentation, and the getter/setter method is mentioned in other places as well, so I'm going with that. Thanks again.

I think the idea of this form builder just overcomplicates everything. After following everything as in that tutorial, my file field value is null. It's being skipped by the handle method of the form.  I removed the constraint property, so there is no validation on it, yet it's null.

Can you provide more code with examples ?

Finally got it after 2 hours of debugging. Renamed the field and it started to work, not sure about the reason though. I stop bothering people , thanks again.
